# How do I document a parameter that is exclusively passed to another function?

Tags: python, pdoc

Suppose I have two functions:

```
def func_a(x, passed_parameter):
    """
    Return ...
    
    Args:
        x: ...
        passed_parameter: Do a specific thing.
    """
    ...
    
def func_b(passed_parameter):
    """
    Return ...
    
    Args:
        passed_parameter: Do a specific thing.
    """
    ...
```

I think it is clear enough that this situation arises in programming, and copy-pasting is not an option for obvious reasons. My question then is, specifically for `pdoc` (Google-style docstrings), how do I document `passed_parameter` in `func_a`. My first thought is just writing

```
passed_parameter: See `func_b`.
```

This is fine, but I was wondering if there is a more preferred way of doing this either in `pdoc`, or a recommended way in a `PEP`. I tried something like "See `func_b.passed_parameter`" but this does not hyperlink to the parameter in `pdoc`.

Comment: The fact that `passed_parameter` is passed (and only passed) to `func_b` is somewhat of an implementation detail. I would simply document what effect `passed_parameter` has on the effect of `func_a`.

Comment: On the other hand, maybe it should not be documented at all. `def func_a(x, **kwargs)` or `def func_a(x, **args)`, with a simple note that additional arguments are passed directly to `func_b` (if `func_a`'s dependency on `func_b` is something you want to document). (Or that any argument that `func_b` accepts are also accepted by `func_a`.)

Comment: Unless "all other" arguments are passed to `func_b` making `func_a` more like a wrapper then I would use @chepner's suggestion that you document the effect that the parameter has on `func_a`. particularly if there is a 3rd parameter in `func_a` passed to `func_c`.